# Change Color TTF Text SDL C

Tags: c, sdl

I've been trying to change the color of a TTF Text but I can't figure out how to do it.I have:

```
SDL_Color color_text = { 0, 0, 0 }; //Text color

SDL_Surface * surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "text text text text text ", color_text);
```

but It looks like a can't change the color in any way. I can store the color in another way if necessary and if possible.

Answer (score 0):

**In order to change any property of the text in question, you would need to render the text all over again.**

Let's say you're starting with a black text, you would have this:

```
SDL_Color color_text = { 0, 0, 0 }; // Text color
SDL_Surface* surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "TEXT", color_text)
```

This would make `"TEXT"` black since `{ 0, 0, 0 }` is the RGB code for black.

If you want to make it red, you can manipulate values, for example:

```
color_text.r = 255;
SDL_Surface* surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "TEXT", color_text)
```

This would make `"TEXT"` red because the `r`member of `color_text` is set to `255`, making `color_text`'s members `{ 255, 0, 0 }`, the RGB code for red.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact possible without re-rendering the text:

If you initially apply a white color, you can use [`SDL_GetSurfaceColorMod`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_GetSurfaceColorMod) on the surface, or [`SDL_GetTextureColorMod`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_GetTextureColorMod) on a texture created from it, so that the text becomes colored copied (e.g. to your main window) with `SDL_BlitSurface`/`SDL_RenderCopy`.